# Getting external params into anonymous function jQuery

Tags: jquery, scope, closures, parameter-passing, anonymous-function

I'm working on a function that will return a context menu for use within a jsTree (http://www.jstree.com/documentation/contextmenu) context. In setting up the context menu object, I need to somehow get some vars into a wrapped call to another function in my integrated plugin.

The fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/9sKF5/12/ and the code is thus:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var treeDef = {
        "rateComponentGroup": {
            title: "Rate Component Group",
            entity: "rateComponentGroup",
            contextMenu: [
                {label: "New...", action: "new", entity: "rateComponentGroup"},
                {label: "Delete...", action: "confirmdelete", entity: "rateComponentGroup"}
            ]
        }

    }

    var clickedNode = "rateComponentGroup";

    if (treeDef[ clickedNode ]) { // do we have setup for this node?

        cntxtMenu = treeDef[ clickedNode ].contextMenu;

        if (cntxtMenu instanceof Array) {

            var menu = {};

            for(var i = 0; i < cntxtMenu.length; i++) {

                // append msg to html to see what we're doing
                $("#message").append(cntxtMenu[i].label + cntxtMenu[i].action + "<br/>");

                // define each context menu item label and action
                menu[i] = {
                    label: cntxtMenu[i].label,
                    action: function() {
                        // 
                        // how to get cntxtMenu[i].label and cntxtMenu[i].action in here?
                        // 
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        // in larger context this block simply returns an object defining a context menu for jsTree
        //    containing a label and an action method to fire when selected
        //    see: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/contextmenu
        // return menu;

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the value of those objects into objects in your menu[] array. Then use their values in the action function()

```
// append msg to html to see what we're doing
$("#message").append(cntxtMenu[i].label + cntxtMenu[i].action + "<br/>");
// define each context menu item label and action
menu[i] = {
   label: cntxtMenu[i].label,
   cntxtAct: cntxtMenu[i].action,
   action: function() {
      // just use the copies in here
      alert(this.label + '\n' + this.cntxtAct);
   }
}
```

Working example @ [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sKF5/21/)

Comment: I wish...but as I tried here, calling the function defined for an action raises error that ctxtMenu is undefined...http://jsfiddle.net/9sKF5/17/

Comment: **Edit:** Edited main post with a new solution that works, store the value of those variables when they are in scope then u can reference the copies later

Comment: Dude you rock, thanks for the insight. This ended up not working in my larger plugin context, but it made me force the issue--it's something to do with the cntxtMenu[i] notation. It worked when I simply set explicit vars for action and entity instead of referencing them within the array with an index. http://jsfiddle.net/9sKF5/22/